# Best way to put vectorized symbols on button? Wingdings button title

Tags: android, button, icons, vector-graphics, wingdings

Suppose I want to draw simple icon on the button surface. Let it be the cross or some letter.

What is the best way to do this? Can I use wingdings or webdings font on button?

Answer (score 0):

As Android uses Unicode (utf-8) you can use any sign defined there, as long your font supports that. Just use copy and paste. The better solutions i think is using ImageButton using images from your drawables folder. This folder can be found in *project/res/drawables* or via Ecplipse Package-Explorer and you should use this to copy and paste your files in place (png, gif and jpg are supported)

In XML layout file a image is assigned the following way to an ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

See also:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: And what if I have no appropriate Unicode character? Can I use simple vectorized graphics of my own?

Comment: Yes, use ImageButton. But you have to convert it in a supported format. Hopefully my latest edit did clarify things more.